# Get the Date Difference in Data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, date, data.table, lapply

I'd like to know how to get the `date difference` of `two column` in `data.table` using the `lapply` in data.table?

```
library(data.table)
  dt <- fread(" ID          Date        ME_Mes     DOB
 A     2017-02-20  0.0000 2016-08-19
             B      2017-02-06  2.3030 2016-03-11
             C     2017-03-20  0.4135 2016-08-19
             D      2017-03-06  0.0480 2016-10-09
             E     2017-04-20  2.4445 2016-05-04")
> dt
   ID       Date ME_Mes        DOB
1:  A 2017-02-20 0.0000 2016-08-19
2:  B 2017-02-06 2.3030 2016-03-11
3:  C 2017-03-20 0.4135 2016-08-19
4:  D 2017-03-06 0.0480 2016-10-09
5:  E 2017-04-20 2.4445 2016-05-04

###I'd like to calculate the difference in weeks for every ID by comparing the DOB-Date.
```

I tired the following:

```
dt[,lapply(.SD, diff.Date), .SDcols = c(4,2), ID] # but did not work!
```

Comment: `dt[,  "diff" := difftime(strptime(dt$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),strptime(dt$DOB, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), units = "weeks")]`

Comment: @Masoud Looks like something worth posting as an answer, though I guess I'd overwrite each col as IDate with := first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `difftime` to get the difference in weeks. Although, you need to convert your columns to `POSIXct`.

In case you want to keep class of your columns as they are, this works:

```
dt[, "DOB_Date" := difftime(strptime(dt$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
                        strptime(dt$DOB,  format = "%Y-%m-%d"), units = "weeks")]

dt
##    ID       Date ME_Mes        DOB       DOB_Date
## 1:  A 2017-02-20 0.0000 2016-08-19 26.43452 weeks
## 2:  B 2017-02-06 2.3030 2016-03-11 47.42857 weeks
## 3:  C 2017-03-20 0.4135 2016-08-19 30.42857 weeks
## 4:  D 2017-03-06 0.0480 2016-10-09 21.14881 weeks
## 5:  E 2017-04-20 2.4445 2016-05-04 50.14286 weeks
```

However, as [@Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988569/r-get-the-date-difference-in-data-table#comment78937691_45988569) suggested it's better to convert ("overwrite") your date-columns to `POSIXct` class first.

Answer (score 3):

My hunch (and I will let others correct me) is that the following is faster on large datasets:

```
dt[,Date:=as.Date(Date)]
dt[,DOB:=as.Date(DOB)]
dt[,datediff:=as.integer(Date)-as.integer(DOB)]
```

`datediff` will contain date differences in days.

If you have a truly large data.table, you may consider `fastPOSIXct` from `fasttime` for string conversion.